# Is it true that $\mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{ (0,0) \}/SO(2) = (0,+\infty)$?

Tags: group-theory, education, quotient-spaces, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

So I want to consider the real plane without the origin. On it $SO(2)$ acts freely. So I can quotient out and obtain $ (0,+\infty)$.
$$\frac{ \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{ (0,0) \}}{SO(2)}  \cong (0,+\infty) $$
 Now, this means I can consider $ (0,+\infty)$ as the base space of a $SO(2)$ principal bundle whose associated vector bundle has fibers isomorphic to the real plane.

I though of this as a nice way to show an easy $G$-bundle construction. Is there any other equivalent or similar construction you would recommend?

Also, if I enhance $SO(2)$ with a $\mathbb{Z_2}$ symmetry what operation do I have to use? I want to take the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with such a group $G$ such that

$$\frac{ \mathbb{R}^2 \backslash \{ (0,0) \}}{G}  \cong \mathbb{R}\backslash \{ 0 \} $$
I guess that it should probably be $G=SO(2)\times \mathbb{Z}_2$. If this is the case, is this group isomorphic to some other group?

Comment: This looks like the First Isomorphism Theorem should be super super handy. I couldn't tell you what to do with it though.

Comment: Yes, the first construction does give you an $SO(2)$-bundle over $(0, \infty)$, but it splits as a product (to see  this think about polar coordinates). The second construction isn't right: a quotient of a connected space cannot be disconnected. If $G = O(2)$, the quotient is still $(0, \infty)$, but the fibres are different.

Comment: Oh. So there's not a homomorphism between $\mathbb{R^2} \backslash \{(0, 0)\} $ and $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$?

Comment: In fact there is no relation $\sim$ on the punctured plane for which $(\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{(0, 0)\}) / {\sim} \cong \Bbb R \{0 \}$, as the punctured plane is connected and the punctured line is not.

Comment: @RobArthan I am confused, which part you mean that splits like a product? Also, I see that indeed, my second construction must be wrong because I got non homotopic spaces but.. intuitively, and only intuitively, I can see that in the first construction I basically care about 1-single line that passes from the origin (excluding) it by adding some sort of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ symmetry. Stupid question: do I have something else on mind?

Comment: Think about polar coordinates! That representation show you to view the punctured plane as the product $S^1 \times (0, \infty)$

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the content of Rob Arthan's comment, but I'll emphasize the language of group actions.

There's a natural identification $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{ (0, 0) \} \leftrightarrow \Bbb R_+ \times \Bbb S^1$: Via the usual Cartesian identification we can regard $\Bbb R^2$ as $\Bbb C$, that is, via $(x, y) \leftrightarrow x + iy$. Then, if we regard $\Bbb S^1$ as the unit circle in $\Bbb C$, the map $$\Bbb R_+ \times \Bbb S^1 \to \Bbb C \setminus \{ 0 \}, \qquad (r, \zeta) \mapsto r\zeta$$ is a homeomorphism, as computing its inverse, $z \mapsto \left(|z|, \frac{z}{|z|}\right)$, immediately gives). Of course, if we write in a suitable open set $\zeta = \exp(i \theta)$ for some continuous choice of $\theta$, then $(r, \theta)$ defines a choice of polar coordinates.

On the other hand, we can also identify $\textrm{SO}(2)$ with $\Bbb S^1$---on $\Bbb S^1$, via the map
$$\Bbb S^1 \to \textrm{SO}(2), \qquad \zeta \mapsto \pmatrix{\textrm{Re}\, \zeta & - \textrm{Im}\, \zeta \\ \textrm{Im}\, \zeta & \textrm{Re}\, \zeta} .$$
In terms of our coordinate $\theta$, the matrix here becomes the familiar $$\pmatrix{\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta} .$$
Checking shows the group action is just (the restriction of) complex multiplication, so if we regard via our identifications the given $\textrm{SO}(2)$ action as an action of $\Bbb S^1$ on $\Bbb R_+ \times \Bbb S^1$, unwinding definitions gives that the action is a product of the trivial action of $\Bbb S^1$ on $\Bbb R_+$ and the canonical multiplication action of $\Bbb S^1$ on itself, that is,
$$\alpha \cdot (r, \zeta) = (r, \alpha \zeta) .$$